# Windows 10 digital activation on few devices

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, motherboard, windows-activation

**My problem is as follows...**

I have a computer with **three disks, on each disk is installed windows 10**. I intend to upgrade the hardware by **replacing the motherboard and processor.** Each windows is activated with digital activation, but on each disk is connected to the same account. I am concerned that after replacing the motherboard I may only be able to activate one windows, of which two drives will remain without an activated system.

My concern comes from the fact that when I go to the microsoft website on a given drive I can only see one device which is the drive I am currently working on.

I know that the problem may be a bit complicated, but **my main question is whether there is a possibility that after replacing the motherboard it will be possible to activate a particular windows on a particular drive using the digital activation option.**

*(I most likely no longer have access to the windows keys I used so this is the only option).*

Comment: Windows 10 activation is handled by a digital entitlement system. You also don’t have three devices, you have one device, and three installations. Unless the motherboard is an OEM motherboard (Dell, HP, ect.) you won’t have a problem changing the motherboard. Why don’t you have your retail license key?

Comment: The first thing is I'm not 100% sure if this is counted as one device, because in the system information on each drive the device name is different (I mean for example DESKTOP-X256KWR) and I don't know if this is a problem (on the microsoft website it is the same), if this is not a problem and I will be able to activate windows from the same email on each drive in that case the topic can be closed.

Speaking of activation keys, most likely the messages containing them were accidentally deleted from my email.

Comment: I am 100% because I am 100% certain I understand how Windows is licensed. Windows is activated based off the hardware configuration. If you can confirm this is a retail license key, there is a tool that exists, that can display the license key with 100% accuracy. [ShowKeyPlus](https://github.com/Superfly-Inc/ShowKeyPlus/releases/tag/ShowKeyPlus1.1.18.0) but it won’t be required. Your installation won’t go into a non-activation status.

Comment: Well in that case I will follow your advice, I will use some program that will help me dig out the keys I used. Then I'll replace the motherboard and try to activate this through a microsoft account, if it doesn't go I'll use those keys hoping it will work.

Thanks a lot for your help!